# jquery change form action

Tags: jquery, forms

There are definitely questions out there to help on this, but I can't seem to get mine working...

Trying to base my form action off of a  menu.  Obviously have something wrong and would appreciate any thoughts!

```
$("#role").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "audience");
    var action = "./";
    } else {
    var action = "http://google.com";
$("#landing_form").attr("action", action);
});

  <form action="./" method="post" id="landing_form">
    <select name="role" id="role">
      <option value="audience">Audience</option>
      <option value="presenter">Presenter</option>
      <option value="moderator">Moderator</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some syntax errors, missing curlybraces etc.

```
$(function() {
    $("#role").on('change', function() {
        if (this.value == "audience") {
            var action = "./";
        } else {
            var action = "http://google.com";
        }
        $("#landing_form").attr("action", action);
    });
});
```

Comment: Your a rock star, worked first time.  Thanks so much for your help!